# String? is not convertible to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following an Apple WatchKit course on Udemy, in which I create an currency conversion type app. The following syntax works for the gentleman in the video, but gives me an error:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
....

currencyConversions[getCurrency] = (string as NSString).doubleValue
```

He states that we need to first convert this object into an NSString, and then convert it into a double. However, I get the following error:

String? is not convertible to 'NSString'

Perhaps he's using a newer version of Swift/Xcode? How can I fix this?

Comment: Well we can't know if he has a newer version unless you tell us his version and your version.

Comment: I'm assuming he's using Xcode 7+, and I'm using Xcode 6.4

Comment: I've attempted unwrapping and it didn't work

Comment: You need to be more specific than "didn't work"

Comment: You should really upgrade to Xcode 7.1, as the Swift language has changed significantly since 6.4. Anyway, try this: `currencyConversions[getCurrency] = string.flatMap { Double($0) }`

Comment: I can't invoke "flatMap"

Comment: When I unwrap the line and execute I get a crash that says "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Comment: Sounds like your `currencyConversions` is an array, and `getCurrency` is not a valid index into that array. That is a completely different problem than “String? is not convertible to 'NSString'”.

Comment: @FaisalSyed123 as rob said. further, if your currencyConversions[getCurrency] don't accept optional value (you sad that you have to unwrap the right side of the assignment) is better to use currencyConversions[getCurrency] = str.flatMap { Double($0) } ?? 0

Answer (score 0):

This works with **Xcode 6.4** and **Xcode 7.1.1**:

Since `s` is an `Optional` `String`, you need to safely unwrap it before casting it as an `NSString`.  Use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to do that:

```
currencyConversions[getCurrency] = ((string ?? "") as NSString).doubleValue
```

Comment: This will solve your `String? is not convertible to NSString` error which is a compile error.  If you are still seeing `fatal error: Array index out of range` on this line, that is a runtime error that is happening because `getCurrency` is bigger than the maximum index of your array.  That is a different problem.

Answer (score -1):

NSString has a constructor that composes it from an ordinary string. Try calling it from NSString(string!), and hopefully then it should work!

Answer (score -1):

You need to unwrap the string object before casting it. Do not forget to check for nil  value for optional object before unwrapping.

```
if (string != nil){
   currencyConversions[getCurrency] = (string! as NSString).doubleValue
}
```